# Extrusion locked on one axis?

Tags: extrude

I'm fairly new to blender. Let's get this out of the way. **This will be poorly explained, but explained to the best of my knowledge.**
I've been working on modelling a head and I now need to extrude a few points on the x axis. The problem is, they seem to have restricted themselves one of the axis. I can't move the original points or the extrusion along any other axis. I know it isn't intentionally locked on because when I press the X, Y, and Z buttons, they all lock on at different angles. What I'm trying to say is, i didn't lock it to anything but I can't move it any way but on some weird version of the Y axis, if that makes sense.

I need to move the points freely. Not locked onto anything. Help me. Please.

**EDIT**
There's no constraints. Nothing should be actually stopping it from moving along the X axis. Nothing that i've checked is locked. [image]

That, in the picture, is the only way I can move the verts. I wouldn't be able to drag it along the X-axis if I wanted to.

Comment: The extrusion happens along the normal axis of the selected face. This is expected behaviour. If you want to avoid that you can either: extrude and cancel moving after that, then move as desired; or delete face and extrude vertices which formed that face. Vertices moving after extrusion won't be locked to any axis. Read http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19321/why-is-extrude-locked-to-z-axis and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41853/unconstrained-extrusion

Comment: Tried both of these things. Tried every possible way to unlock it from whatever constraint it's on. No luck.

Comment: Try turning off *Clipping* in the *Mirror* modifier