# Why is this plus sign in a yellow circle appearing on the selected face?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, extrude

I am new to blender (about a week working after work). And I face this problem that I have this plus sign in yellow circle. And I am not sure how to get rid of it. I have no idea what is the name of it (if I would know name I probably would google it).
This happens in edit mode.

[image: I don't know w3hat it is]

Comment: check your tools panel, on the left of your 3D View (displayed with T), you must have activated the Extrusion tool, select another one

Comment: I want to use extrusion tool, but before there was no yellow circle, anyway I found workaround here [middle click to use any axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19322/98637)

Comment: because you can either click on the tool or activate it with the shortcut E, in that case you won't see the yellow point

Comment: awesome, thank you :))) now it's very clear. I tried it out and it works like you say :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your *Tools* panel, on the left of your 3D View (displayed with <kbd>T</kbd>), you must have activated the *Extrusion* tool, select another one if you want. To use the *Extrusion* tool, you can either click on it on the *Tools* panel, or activate it with the shortcut <kbd>E</kbd>, in that case you won't see the yellow point (and you will stay in your current selected tool).